# Count a special column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can i count the data from a column if sort them first

```
SELECT  * FROM erfasst
WHERE jahr >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
AND jahr < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```

[image]

I need the output from gesamt (4589) as result. If there are many results, mysql should count the gesamt column together.

Comment: "count the `gesamt` column together" = sum all found `gesamt` columns? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to sum all values of `gesamt`:

```
SELECT SUM(gesamt) AS gesamt 
FROM erfasst
WHERE jahr >= curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())+6 DAY
    AND jahr < curdate() - INTERVAL DAYOFWEEK(curdate())-1 DAY
```